# Filter Data Per Value of Independent Variable in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-processing

I am quite new to R and data processing in general so please forgive me if my use of terminology is poor.

I have some data with a discrete, non-unique independent variable DeltaT and an dependent values called Score.

I would like to keep only the top 5 percentile (remove everything LT 0.95 percentile) of the scores for each value in DeltaT.

The following figure depicts what I am trying to do accomplish.

[image: Example in Excel]

I am under the impression there are ways to do this without loops but don't know the names of the functions I may need.

Comment: Can you post the data using `dput` of your R data frame object? Hard to import data from an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a base R solution using [`quantile()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/quantile.html), [`ave()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ave.html), comparison, and indexing:

```
df <- data.frame(DeltaT=c(1L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,3L,3L,4L,4L,4L),Score=1:12);
df[df$Score>=ave(df$Score,df$DeltaT,FUN=function(x) quantile(x,0.95)),];
##    DeltaT Score
## 3       1     3
## 5       2     5
## 9       3     9
## 12      4    12
```

---

Your example data is not ideal because it does not cover the case of multiple `Score` values satisfying the filter condition. I wrote my solution under the assumption that you want to keep all rows that satisfy the condition. Here's a better test:

```
df <- data.frame(DeltaT=c(1L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L,3L,3L,3L,4L,4L,4L,4L),Score=c(1:12,12));
df[df$Score>=ave(df$Score,df$DeltaT,FUN=function(x) quantile(x,0.95)),];
##    DeltaT Score
## 3       1     3
## 5       2     5
## 9       3     9
## 12      4    12
## 13      4    12
```

Comment: Both this answer and the answer provided by @Gopala work. This solution is preferred as it solves my problem using only native datatypes and functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without having your data, I created my own. Here is one approach that can help you with the solution using a quantile function to get the 95th percentile value and using `dplyr` package's grouping and filtering functions:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(DeltaT = c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 10)), Score = c(1:10, 1:10))
df %>% group_by(DeltaT) %>% filter(Score >= quantile(Score, probs = 0.95))
```

Output in this case will be as only these two scores match the 95th percentile or above:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
Groups: DeltaT [2]

  DeltaT Score
   <dbl> <int>
1      1    10
2      2    10
```

You can change the code suit your specific needs if any.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(data.table)


setDT(df) # convert your dataset into a data.table


output <- df[  score >  quantile(df$score, c(.95)), # filter condition
              .(score=score),                       # output column 
              by=.(DeltaT) ]                        # grouped by
```

Answer (score 0):

**dplyr** can be very helpful.
Assuming "df2" is your data.frame

```
> library(dplyr)
> group_by(df2, DeltaT) %>% summarise(Score = round(quantile(Score, probs=0.95),0))
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

  DeltaT   Score
   (dbl) (dbl)
1      1     3
2      2     5
3      3     9
4      4    12
```

Comment: This gives you the 95th percentile score. Not rows that have that score or above. See my answer below.

Comment: Right, but why post another answer that is the same solution as one posted below.

Comment: I didn't see yours :-)